# Can retrieve one record from database but not another using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, discord

So, for a school project, I am building a discord bot. One of the features that I have built in is that he can retrieve gif links from a MySQL database, and send them in a message. Now, my issue is that I am only able to retrieve one record from my database, and no other records. If I put the query that I use into MySQL workbench and run it, it will retrieve those records.

This is the method for retrieving the gifs

```
public static ArrayList<Gif> GetGifsFromDB(String msg){
    ArrayList<Gif> gifs = new ArrayList<>();

    try(Connection conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password)){
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "Select * from gif WHERE Type = '" + msg + "'";
        stmnt.execute(sql);

        try(ResultSet rs = stmnt.getResultSet()){
            while(rs.next()){
            Gif g = new Gif();
            g.setID(rs.getInt("GifID"));
            g.setURL(rs.getString("GifURL"));
                System.out.println(g.getID() + g.getURL());
            gifs.add(g);
        }
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
        }

    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return gifs;
}
```

The "Type" in the database it just a category. With the test data I have in there, the 3 types are no, surprised and lonely. Only no returns a gif.

Comment: What do you get if you execute your final `sql` query directly on the database ?

Comment: If I run it directly, it returns the record I am trying to get back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue  ended up being with MySql not committing records to the database. Once workbench was refreshed, the added records disappeared. Rather strange that even though the records weren't in the database, they could be retrieve.

Comment: If the insert and select statements were running in the same transaction, it makes sense - the query was run, returned the new rows, and _then_ the insertion was rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

Remove closing ResultSet and Connection lines:

```
 rs.close();
 conn.close();
```

You are already closing it using try-with-resources

Comment: The `List<Gif>` should be completely filled before closing the resources explicitly, but you are right, the `try (Connection conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password))` should close it anyway...

Comment: I removed those lines, but the issue still remains.

Comment: @ZacBeatty-Taylor can you also replace with `ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sql)`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `msg` is not exactly matching with any of the values for the database `Type` column.

Test by running

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gif WHERE Type = '... put msg content here ...'
```

Do this manually directly on the database.

You can also try to put following line of code at the end:

```
System.out.println("Number of Selected Gifs: "+gifs.size());
```

If either of those results zero, then it means that `msg` was not exactly matched with `Type`. Maybe uppercase/lowercase issue?

Also to avoid SQL Injection, and other issues, please strongly consider using bind variables using a `PreparedStatement`.